# Delete commit from a branch

Tags: git

I'm working with git on two different branches at the same time (ex `feature/feature_1` and `feature/feature_2`)

On `feature/feature_1`, I started from the master, and I already pushed some commits (but not merged).

For `feature/feature_2`, I wanted to start from master as well, but unfortunately, I started from `feature/feature_1`, and I didn't notice it at the beginning, and I pushed some commits.

So on `feature/feature_2` I have every commit from `feature/feature_1` (that I don't want on this branch), plus some other commits that I want to keep.

How can I "remove" the commit from `feature_1` that I have on `feature_2`, without deleting the work I have already done on `feature_2`.

I would point out that both branches are already pushed but are not merged yet, and have nothing in common.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way:

```
git rebase --onto master feature/feature_1 feature/feature_2
```

That's it

Comment: This is the best answer, but I can never remember the order to put the commits, so I always fall back to interactive rebasing.

Comment: It's very simple: `git rebase --onto new-base drop-this rebase-this`

Comment: Yeah I know it every time I see it explained. Then I forget again.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout `feature_2`:

```
$ git checkout feature/feature_2
```

Do an interactive rebase against master:

```
$ git rebase -i master
```

Delete all of the commits you don't want on `feature_2` in the editor that comes up, then save and exit.

You'll need to force push your branch if you need others to see the changes - this operation is changing history.

Comment: Anytime you edit history on a pushed branch you need to force push and then inform any other users of that branch so that they know to force pull when they update.